# Does it make sense to talk about a square or rectangular cyclide when we invert a square or rectangular torus?

Tags: geometry, parametrization, conformal-geometry, inversive-geometry

In [Conformal Tiling on a Torus](https://static1.bridgesmathart.org/2011/cdrom/proceedings/134/paper_134.pdf), the author John M. Sullivan provides a conformal parameterization of the torus. The conformality is associated to the so-called aspect ratio $s = \sqrt{\frac{R^2}{r^2}-1}$. For example, the *square* torus is the one for which $s=1$, and that means that a square pattern conformally fits on this torus.

Can we "transport" this notion by a geometric inversion? The inversion of a torus with respect to a sphere is a cyclide. Does it make sense to talk about a "square cyclide" if the torus is square? And more generally does it make sense to talk about the aspect ratio of the cyclide?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, _yes_: A torus with a Riemannian metric has a conformally well-defined lattice up to non-zero complex scaling, i.e., conformally equivalent metrics have the same lattice up to complex scaling. A rectangular torus consequently has a well-defined aspect ratio if (say) we take "long side/short side." <> Commenting instead of answering since there may be technical details (such as a proof, or proof sketch) you'd like to see, and time doesn't currently permit....